# using regex to find a ether address

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use a regex expression to find a ether address. im pretty new to regex so id apparated a bit of help explaining why my code is returning a null value. its probably something to do with the expression its self. `row` has two ether address in it.

```
row = 'afdsf1 asdfasdf0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f48c348958880537835fdsgdsfg 0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f48c348958880537835f'
all_match = re.findall(pattern= '^0x[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$', string=row)
for match in all_match:
    print(match.group())
print(all_match)
```

Comment: With `^` you force the match to be at the start of the string, and with `$` the end of the string. Just drop these two anchors in your matching pattern.

Comment: The `^` and `$` characters in the regex match the start and end of the string. You want matches anywhere in the string so remove these characters and it should work how you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the regex and remove `^`. re.findall() will return list of strings with this pattern `'0x[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$'`.

```py
row = 'afdsf1 asdfasdf0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f48c348958880537835fdsgdsfg 0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f48c3z48958880537835f'
all_match = re.findall(pattern='0x[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$', string=row)
for match in all_match:
    print(match)
```

> 0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f48c348958880537835f

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).